# How to find processes which uses the most RAM in last X seconds?

Tags: monitoring, ram

Could you please help me to sort this out?
I'm trying to write a bash script which will monitor ram usage (not only ram but cpu and network as well) and show me 3 processes which use the most ram in past X seconds? 
I know that I can find which processes use the most ram by running the following:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $2, $4, $11}' | sort -k2rn | head -n 3
```

But how can this be repeated? I want to see not the situation at this exactly second, but monitor the situation for (let it be) 60 seconds and see top 3 processes which was using the most ram.

Comment: You can try `watch "ps aux | awk '{print $2, $4, $11}' | sort -k2rn | head -n 3", you can look into using `top -b` and passing it additional sorting parameters, and there are also other tools like `sar` and `vmstat` that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use the `dstat` command. Very useful. Explore it using `man dstat`

For example:

Find most expensive in terms of memory every 3 seconds:

`#dstat --top-mem 3
--most-expensive-
memory process 
firefox     1430M
firefox     1430M
firefox     1431M
firefox     1435M
firefox     1435M
firefox     1435M
firefox     1435M
firefox     1438M`

Similarly you can dot it for cpu , network , IO , etc.

`dstat --top-cpu 3
-most-expensive-
cpu process

firefox      3.5
firefox      4.5
firefox      2.4
firefox      2.6
firefox      2.8
firefox      2.0
firefox      2.8`

Comment: Can it show the pid of the process ? Maybe there're many firefox process running on the system

Answer (score 0):

Top 3 memory hungry processes command:

ps auxxx --sort=-rss | head -4

Top 3 cpu hungry processes:

ps auxxx --sort=-%cpu | head -4

You can run these scripts through Cronjob at every minute.

- - - - - /tmp/serverhealth.sh